# Why is Shimano's 105 groupset called 105?

Tags: shimano, history

Shimano's current road lineup is
Claris / Sora / Tiagra / 105 / Ultegra / Duraace

105 stands out as odd because its a number.  Is there some special meaning ?

[image: from https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/105-5800.html]

---

Research

- 105 was released in 1983 as a 6 speed groupset under the name "A105 Golden Arrow"
- At the time Ultegra was known as "600" so some consistency in a 3 digit number.   Dura Ace was always called Dura Ace, and Ultegra got its name in 1997
- MTB groupsets have always had a name.  There are no numbers for the groupset as a whole, though each year's revision has a model number.

Conjecture from the web

- 105 is the reverse of 501, which came from Levi's Jeans, popular in the late 80s in Japan and matching the "workhorse reliable" nature of the 105.
- 105 reads as "SOI" or "501" when rotated 180 degrees.  But SOI is not a Japanese nor English word, like Dura-Ace ( Duralumin alloy + Ace 'best') or Ultegra = ( ultimate" + Integrity)
- In the late 80s Shimano introduced SIS shifting and SLR braking.  At this time many groupsets were stopped, like the 200GS, 300GS, 400GS, 500EX, and Exage.  New groupsets with SIS/SLR replaced them over time.

So why has "105" persevered ?

Comment: Might be a good idea to forward this question to Shimano on Twitter or FB. I couldn't find any email contacts on Shimano website.

Comment: I've contacted the PR person of my region, 'll give an update if they can redirect me to someone that could know more.

Comment: My guess is like the fabled "Gorilla story", no one at Shimano has been squirted with a fire hose, but they still call it 105  - the reason why lost to the mists of time. That does not stop me hoping someone has the answer though.

Comment: @mattnz yep - there's plenty of different disagreeing opinions on the web, and no definitive answers.

Comment: Possibly related - I came across the "rule of 105" in a GCN video.  The rule says "the rim must be at least 105% the width of the tire if you have any chance of re-capturing airflow from the tire and controlling it or smoothing it.  " as mentioned in  https://web.archive.org/web/20180428033729/https://silca.cc/blogs/journal/part-5-tire-pressure-and-aerodynamics 
 and  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/55483/19705   Probably a coincidence, but relevant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a non-answer because I've been looking at Japanese bicycling sites and blogs and no one really knows. The closest [answer is found here:](https://rakuride.jp/question/20180402082652.html)

> 105の名の由来とは？
>
> 最後に、各グレード名の由来についての豆知識を紹介します。1971年に誕生したデュラエースの名は、素材のジュラルミン（Duralumin）と耐久性を意味するデュラビリティ（Durability）に、世界一のコンポという願いを込めた「エース」を組み合わせた造語です。1976年に誕生のアルテグラは、Ultimate（究極）+Integrate（統合）を意味するコンポーネントです。1982年に誕生した105については、当時のダブルレバーSL-A105の型番を継承し、現在では105というグレード名になっています。

which google translate translate (with some clean-up) as:

> What is the origin of the 105 name?
>
> Finally, I will introduce my knowledge about the origin of each grade name [in the Shimano series]. The name of Dura Ace which was born in 1971 is a combination of Duralumin of the material and Durability meaning durability combined with "Ace" which wish of the world's best component. The birth of Ultegra in 1976 is a component that means Ultimate + Integrate. Concerning 105 which was born in 1982, it inherited the model number of the double lever SL-A 105 at that time and now it has become the grade name of 105.

So it's a non-answer answer. The author of this article, Kenji Hashimoto, is a sports journalist in Japan and so it's about as close as one might get unless you ask Shimano.

Comment: For historical interest: duralumin is the old name for what we would now call 2000-series aluminum alloys. That name appears to have been used in bicycle and bike component manufacturing from the 1930s to around the 80s. I don't know material properties, but I believe these alloys have been superseded by 6000 and 7000-series alloys in the bike industry. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duralumin

Comment: I can go with the journalist's origin story for the 105 name. "105 is one more than 104" was the best reason I could come up with. It makes me happy to know that I didn't waste your time with such a juvenile answer! To me, the Golden Arrow design remains stunning. In searching Shimano shifters as stylish key fobs & potential a draft beer levers (prototyping seems to be persistently ongoing.), I find the friction shifters that have any 'object' graphic somewhere on the levers are quite elegantly embellished.